# Duplicate the documents in same collection in mongo

Tags: mongodb

Is there a way to duplicate the records in a collection into the same collection ? I am trying to generate lots of records and hence this is needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you just want to duplicate easy way is like below

```
db.col1.find({},{_id:0}).forEach(function(doc){db.col1.save(doc)});
```

Answer (score 0):

A quick but maybe not the most efficient way to do that could be:

- Get all the documents of the collection
- For each one re-write the ObjectId with a new value
- Insert the modified document inside the collection

With mongo shell you could do that using the **forEach** as follows:

```
db.getCollection('YOUR_COLLECTION').find({}).forEach(
    function(doc){
        doc._id = new ObjectId();
        db.getCollection('YOUR_COLLECTION').insert(doc); 
    }
)
```

This way, each time you run this query, all the documents in the collection are duplicated.